# Knockout js with jquery DataTables memory not releasing

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

Hello all I have a Singalr, MVC5, Knockoutjs, jQuery Datatables project for auto updating data. However I am having a huge issue with memory size keeps growing and never releases as see in the picture here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WScB.jpg

Here is my code I've been beating my head against my desk for a few days now and I've even tried converting this to a full viewmodel. Any help out there pleaseeee :(

So i made some of the suggested changes but now the table doesn't redraw any data afterwards and the memory still grows what did I do wrong here.

//Updated code

```
 function loadAlerts(newAlerts, alertsObservable) {
        alertsObservable([]);
        var alerts = [];
        alerts = newAlerts;
        alertsObservable(alerts);
        $('#alarmsTable').DataTable().clear().draw();
    }

    function AlertsViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.hub = $.connection.alarmsHub;
        self.alarms = ko.observableArray();
        self.activate = function (alertsObservable) {
            alertsObservable([]);
            self.hub.server.getAllAlarms().done(pass).fail(failure);
            function pass(data) {
                var alerts = [];
                alerts = data;
                alertsObservable(alerts);
                console.log('Passed: SignalR will begin, refresh is sent every 1 min.');
                loadDataTable(alerts);
            }
            function failure() {
                console.log('Something happened, the query to the database failed.');
            }
        };

        self.hub.client.updateAlarms = function (broadCastAlarms) {
            loadAlerts(broadCastAlarms, vm.alarms);
            console.log('Broadcaseted Changes');
        };

        self.refresh = function () {
            vm.activate(vm.alarms);
        }
    }

    var vm = new AlertsViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }, function () { vm.activate(vm.alarms) });


    //Let's put back any values we stored to the input boxes
    var cookies = $.cookie();
    for (var name in cookies) {
        $('input[name="' + name + '"]').val(cookies[name]);
    }
});
```

Comment: What calls refreshAlarms, how often and what is in `data`?

Comment: Its a serverside db query every 1 min to pull all the records from the database. The database is being disposed as well right after it pulls the data to a list.

Comment: So data in `hub.client.refreshAlarms = function (data) {` - is that the records from the DB?

Comment: that is just there to call loadAlerts() again on the serverside timer

Comment: i guess what i am getting at is why are you recreating the entire table every 1 minute. Rather than just emptying its rows and replacing them (or appending them)

Comment: $('#alarmsTable').DataTable().clear();
        $('#alarmsTable').DataTable().destroy();

That should delete the table data and then i recreate it.

Comment: This, for example ` $("#clearSorting").click(function () {` is going to add a handler for each call.

Comment: Yes, i get that, and in the same $.get you are declaring your datatables constantly. Do this just once. Then in your $get just redraw with the records.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a quick example?

Comment: not at the moment, sorry. Essentially aim to have `loadAlerts` just fetch the records and then put them into your datatables. Declare the datatables and all other listeners outside of that function. that way you don't have to keep unbinding/destroying/ etc

Comment: I am not sure how that would be accomplished though because it would push a ton of duplicated records over and over again without destroying / unbinding the old data.

Comment: Destroy the data - yes. Destroy the entire table and rebuild it - no. It's difficult at first, though you need to break that big huge method up into bite-sized pieced. A method should do 1 job. yours is doing everything. have your method fetch the records. then give those records to another method that replaces the datatables data. separation of concerns. This will also really help you pin down precisely where any bottleneck is. Also, google Datatables memory leak - there are some issues with the destroy (least there used to be)

Comment: So i made some of the suggested changes but now the table doesn't redraw any data afterwards and the memory still grows what did I do wrong here.